# how to change the array key name in for loop in php

Tags: php, for-loop

I have loop like this

**Code**

```
<?php
for ($i = 'd'; $i<'zz'; $i++) {
    $alpha[] = $i;
}
//$alpha[26] = 'z';

print_r($alpha);
```

As of now output is like this

***Output***

```
Array ( [0] => d [1] => e [2] => f [3] => g [4] => h [5] => i [6] => j [7] => k [8] => l [9] => m [10] => n [11] => o [12] => p [13] => q [14] => r [15] => s [16] => t [17] => u [18] => v [19] => w [20] => x [21] => y....
```

***Expected Output***

```
 Array ( [6] => d [7] => e [8] => f [9] => g [10] => h ....
```

so what im trying to do is changing the key name key name will starts from `[6]=>d,[7]=>e....` so on i need how can i do that in php ?

Comment: yes ur right :) @Epodax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still a tad unsure if this is what you want, but you can make a simple increment counter like this:

```
$x = 6; //X is your array's new starting point

for ($i = 'd'; $i<'zz'; $i++) {
    $alpha[$x] = $i;
    $x++; //Increment X with 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, just add the index manually

```
<?php
$index = 6;
for ($i = 'd'; $i<'zz'; $i++) {
    $alpha[$index] = $i;
    $index++;
}

print_r($alpha);
```